# how to dynamically change end of url in retrofit2

Tags: java, android, post, path, retrofit2

I'm trying to change end of URL dynamically in POST request.

```
@POST("/api/registrations/{key}")
Call<RegistrationResponse> confirmRegister(
   @Body RegisterParam registerParam, @Path("key") String key);

 D/OkHttp: --> POST http://base_url/api/registrations/ http/1.1
08-18 18:44:43.138 20510-20672/ D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
08-18 18:44:43.138 20510-20672/ D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 72
 D/OkHttp: <-- 404 Not Found base_url/registrations (449ms)
08-18 18:44:43.588 20510-20672/ D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 18 Aug 2016 12:44:44 GMT
```

I'm going to get result like this:

```
POST base_url/api/registrations/ajksdiuqwdqhiwuqdhiquhd
```

Comment: and where is Your qestion?

Comment: show error or smth

Comment: sorry, changed my question

Comment: Please add `java` tag (and `android`?).

Comment: are You sure "key" should be on ulr? not no Post body. or try add / and the end of /api/registrations/{key}/ sometimes servers need this

Comment: not sure. I'm founding it crazy. Fronted developer gived it me.
but with this lib you can do this. https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign

Comment: @mdzht where did you specified the base url?

Comment: @Path is good to change end of url in post.. but error 404 its about wrong endpoint / base url.

Comment: @Soham I renamed to base_url. there's no problem

Answer (score 0):

It was'nt @POST request but @PATCH request. the code, below, works as expected. Sorry for leading astray. Thanks to all.

```
@PATCH("/api/registrations/{key}")
Call<RegistrationResponse> confirmRegister(
@Body RegisterParam registerParam, @Path("key") String key);
```